# move content from one table to another table and add a new value

Tags: mysql

I need to move content from one table to another table, this part is done:

```
INSERT INTO `insc_mwc`
(`nome`,`empresa_idempresa`,`cat_mwc_idcat`,`points_pontos`,`n_registo`)
SELECT nome,empresa_idempresa,cat_mwc_idcat,0
FROM temp_mwc WHERE temp_mwc.empresa_idempresa=$id;
```

How I can give value to `n_registo`, this value is the same for each time the query is executed.

output of  SHOW CREATE TABLE insc_mwc

```
CREATE TABLE `insc_mwc` (
 `idwater` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nome` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `categoria` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `empresa_idempresa` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `mwccar_idcat` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `points_pontos` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `n_registo` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`idwater`),
 KEY `fk_water_empresa1_idx` (`empresa_idempresa`),
 KEY `fk_water_mwccar1_idx` (`mwccar_idcat`),
 KEY `fk_water_points1_idx` (`points_pontos`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_water_empresa1` FOREIGN KEY (`empresa_idempresa`) REFERENCES `empresa` (`idempresa`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_water_mwccar1` FOREIGN KEY (`mwccar_idcat`) REFERENCES `cat_mwc` (`idcat`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_water_points1` FOREIGN KEY (`points_pontos`) REFERENCES `points` (`pontos`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Please show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE insc_mwc\G`

Comment: Umm add your value after 0?

Comment: I posted an answer, but I can make me answer if you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE insc_mwc\G`

Comment: Is `nome` a UNIQUE value ?

Comment: Please run `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM insc_mwc;` and post the output

Answer (score 0):

Your table needs to be like this

```
CREATE TABLE `insc_mwc` (
 `idwater` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nome` varchar(45) NOT NULL, -- Make nome NOT NULL
 `categoria` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `empresa_idempresa` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `mwccar_idcat` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `points_pontos` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `n_registo` INT DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (`idwater`),
 UNIQUE KEY (`nome`), -- Add unique index on nome
 KEY `fk_water_empresa1_idx` (`empresa_idempresa`),
 KEY `fk_water_mwccar1_idx` (`mwccar_idcat`),
 KEY `fk_water_points1_idx` (`points_pontos`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_water_empresa1` FOREIGN KEY (`empresa_idempresa`) REFERENCES `empresa` (`idempresa`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_water_mwccar1` FOREIGN KEY (`mwccar_idcat`) REFERENCES `cat_mwc` (`idcat`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_water_points1` FOREIGN KEY (`points_pontos`) REFERENCES `points` (`pontos`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

To get this, first make sure `nome` is unique by running this:

```
SELECT nome,COUNT(1) DupCount FROM insc_mwc GROUP BY nome HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

If you get nothing back (Empty Set) from this query, then you can safely run

```
ALTER TABLE insc_mwc MODIFY n_registo INT DEFAULT 0, ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`nome`);
```

With a unique `nome` and `n_registo` as an INT, you can increment `n_registo` for each time there is a `DUPLICATE KEY` on `nome`. The `INSERT` can now be done like this:

```
INSERT INTO `insc_mwc`
(`nome`,`empresa_idempresa`,`cat_mwc_idcat`,`points_pontos`)
SELECT nome,empresa_idempresa,cat_mwc_idcat
FROM temp_mwc WHERE temp_mwc.empresa_idempresa=$id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE n_registo = n_registo + 1;
```

Comment: You're adding an integer to a VARCHAR?

Comment: my ideia its add a value, generated by me, and that value is the same for each time this query is executed, i give you an exemple, now I have 10 itens in temp_mwc, i want copy this 10 itens to insc_mwc and add the same value of n_registo, and if I add more n_registo have a different value, I know im a complicated person